# Finding the competitive equilibrium in an exchange economy with two perfect complements

Tags: utility, competitive-equilibrium, pure-exchange-economy, perfect-complements

I am currently in a Microeconomics class and have come across the problem described below. I have tried to solve the problem algebraically but only get to the intercept (x1a,x2a)=(8,4). I know that this is not the only solution so I would appreciate any help!

Consider an exchange economy with two goods (1 and 2) and two consumers ( A and B). The preferences of the two consumers are:

[image: e]

Consumer A is endowed with k1 of good 1 and k2 of good 2. Consumer B owns only 12-k1 of good 1 and 12-k2 of good 2. First, solve the utility maximization problem of each consumer. Then, find all competitive equilibria of this economy for any k1, k2 between 0 and 12. Finally, characterize the contract curve of this economy.

[image]

Comment: "*I have tried to solve the problem algebraically but only get to the intercept*" Can you please edit the question so that it includes your calculations? It is not trivial to see where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Given a pure-exchange economy with

- $u_A(x_A,y_A)=\min(x_A,2y_A)$, $u_B(x_B,y_B)=\min(2x_B,y_B)$
- Endowment of A is $(k_X,k_Y)$ and of B is $(12-k_X,12-k_Y)$

Set of feasible allocations is $\mathcal{F} = \{((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+|x_A+x_B=y_A+y_B=12\}$

Here is the Edgeworth box representation of feasible allocations and set of efficient allocations:
[image]

To determine the competitive equilibrium, we can consider the following cases for the endowments.

**Case 1**: $k_X\leq 8, k_Y\geq 4, (k_X,k_Y)\neq (8,4)$

In this case, given $(k_X,k_Y)$, there is a unique competitive equilibrium allocation $((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))=((8,4),(4,8))$ supported by prices $(p_X,p_Y)=(k_Y-4,8-k_X)$.

[image]

**Case 2**: $(k_X,k_Y)= (8,4)$

In this case, there is a unique competitive equilibrium allocation $((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))=((8,4),(4,8))$ and it can be supported by any pair of prices from the set $\{(p_X,p_Y)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|p_X+p_Y=1\}$.

[image]

**Case 3**: $k_X\geq  8, k_Y \leq 4, (k_X,k_Y)\neq (8,4)$

In this case, given $(k_X,k_Y)$, there are three sets of competitive equilibria:

(i) $((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))=((8,4),(4,8))$ and it is supported by prices $(p_X,p_Y)=(4-k_Y,k_X-8)$.

(ii) Allocations in the set $\{((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathcal{F}|y_A=k_Y, 2k_Y\leq x_A\leq \frac{k_Y+12}{2}\}$ are supported by the prices $(p_X,p_Y)=(0,1)$

(iii) Allocations in the set $\{((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathcal{F}|x_A=k_X, \frac{k_X}{2}\leq y_A\leq 2k_X-12\}$ are supported by the prices $(p_X,p_Y)=(1,0)$

[image]

**Case 4**: $k_X>  8, k_Y > 4$

In this case, given $(k_X,k_Y)$, allocations in the set $\{((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathcal{F}|x_A=k_X, \frac{k_X}{2}\leq y_A\leq 2k_X-12\}$ are supported by the prices $(p_X,p_Y)=(1,0)$

**Case 5**: $k_X<  8, k_Y < 4$

In this case, given $(k_X,k_Y)$, allocations in the set $\{((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathcal{F}|y_A=k_Y, 2k_Y\leq x_A\leq \frac{k_Y+12}{2}\}$ are supported by the prices $(p_X,p_Y)=(0,1)$

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this clears things up a bit, but I still have two more questions:

In **Case 4**: Can't the competitive equilibrium also be ya=k2, xa=6+k2/2 supported by prices (px,py)=(0,1). At this point, the utility of both consumers would be maximized and the outcome would be Pareto efficient. 

Furthermore, in **Case 1** why can't there be 3 sets of equilibria as in **Case 3**, I'm not sure I understand what prevents the equilibrium from being for example : (xA,yA)=(kx, 0<yA<kx/2) supported by prices (px,py)=(1,0)